# Show tags in Wordpress without last separator

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags();
if( $tags ) :
    echo '<p class="taxonomy"><span class="tag-title">'.__('Tags: ', 'warp').'</span>';
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        echo '<span class="'. $tag->slug .'"><a href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name .'</a></span>';
    }
echo '</p>';
endif; ?>
```

I want to use this code to show tags on pages. One function I want to use needs get_the_tags() to make it work as I wanted. I got suggested to use implode() to get rid of last separator from tag list. I don't know PHP good enough to implement it into this piece of code. The best result I got was: `Tags: tag | | tag | | and so on`. I know there are answers to similar questions but none of them worked with this code.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With big help from one user it's finally done. Hiding last separator with this code looks like that:

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags();
if( $tags ) :
    echo '<p class="taxonomy"><span class="tag-title">'.__('Tags: ', 'warp').'</span>';
    foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
        $names[] = '<span class="'. $tag->slug .'"><a href="'. get_tag_link($tag->term_id) .'">'. $tag->name .'</a></span>';
    }
echo implode(' | ', $names ) .'</p>';
endif; ?>
```